# Why does `get` work on both std::vec::Vec and &std::vec::Vec?

Tags: rust, reference

I'm confused why the function `get` works with both `Vec<T>` and `&Vec<T>`. I know that `&Vec<T>` automatically converts to `&[T]` so in some sense, the question is why it works on `Vec<T>` as well as `&[T]`. Obviously, `get` works with `&[T]`, so is it separately implemented for `Vec<T>` in addition to the implementation for `&[T]`? Looking at the docs, it doesn't seem like it, there is only one `get` implementation: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.get

In the following code, `get` is acting on `Vec<T>`.

```
fn first<T: PartialOrd + Copy>(list: Vec<T>) -> T {
    *list.get(0).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let number_list = vec![34, 50, 25, 100, 65];
    let result = first(number_list);
    println!("The first number is {}", result);
}
```

In this code, it is acting on `&Vec<T>` (aka `&[T]`):

```
fn first<T: PartialOrd + Copy>(list: &Vec<T>) -> T {
    *list.get(0).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let number_list = vec![34, 50, 25, 100, 65];
    let result = first(&number_list);
    println!("The first number is {}", result);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to automatic referencing.

From [Method Syntax](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html) in The Rust Programming Language...

> Rust has a feature called *automatic referencing and dereferencing* [...] when you call a method with `object.something()`, Rust automatically adds in `&`, `&mut`, or `*` so object matches the signature of the method. In other words, the following are the same:
>
> ```
> p1.distance(&p2);
> (&p1).distance(&p2);
> ```
>
> The first one looks much cleaner. This automatic referencing behavior works because methods have a clear receiver—the type of `self`. Given the receiver and name of a method, Rust can figure out definitively whether the method is reading (`&self`), mutating (`&mut self`), or consuming (`self`). The fact that Rust makes borrowing implicit for method receivers is a big part of making ownership ergonomic in practice.